# Finding shuffled column indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bit of a weird problem of relating 2 numpy matrices (2d-arrays) to another. I think the problem is best described as having two matrices `A` and `B` for which B's indices of the axis=1 have been shuffled (the values of `A` and `B`, the position along the column axis (=1) is just different). What I am trying to find is the index map *m* for which `A[:,m] == B` so I know which column in `B` relates to which column in `A`.

Here is an example (given `a` and `b`, I'd like to find `m`):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(70, 300)
# we set up `m` to demonstrate the issue, but in fact that's not given
>>> m = np.asarray(list(range(300)))
>>> m
array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,
        26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,
        39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,
        52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,
        65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,
        78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,
     ...
>>> np.random.shuffle(m)
>>> m
array([209, 198,  17, 150, 181, 169,  47,  29, 109, 137, 149,   8,  85,
       251, 254, 191, 133,  40, 106, 243, 202, 101, 269,  23, 248,  49,
         3, 160,  88, 192, 166, 105, 283, 171, 128, 211, 206, 235, 185,
        37, 250,  66, 272, 259, 260,  14,  50, 256,  10, 238, 177,  15,
        51, 293,  53, 197,  11, 296, 111, 167,  86, 155, 215, 234,  80,
        76,  42, 216, 104, 144,  90,  45,  70, 126,  30, 117,   6, 139,
       299, 232, 182,  95, 129, 217,  55, 279, 118, 189, 180, 285, 157,
        79, 159, 294,  68, 244,  91,  52,  56, 127, 187, 131, 292, 164,
       132,  38,  87, 265, 173, 123, 154,  26, 143, 223, 276, 257, 263,
        93, 261, 179, 186, 267,  59, 221,  44,  31,  21,   9, 194,  25,
     ...
>>> b = a[:, m] # initialise `b`
>>> (a == b).all()
False
>>> (b == a[:, m]).all()
True
```

Another intricacy comes from the fact that the matrix is actually a little sparse which means there may be a number of possible versions of *m* (but I don't expect too many as the number of rows is relatively large and should limit the number of ambiguities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a pure numpyic way of doing that.
a simple for loop on the 1st dimension of A can retrieve m.

```
import numpy as np
shape = (5, 5)
A = np.random.rand(*shape)
# we set up `m` to demonstrate the issue, but in fact that's not given
m = np.asarray(list(range(shape[1])))
np.random.shuffle(m)
B = A[:, m]
```

for each column i in B we can find the column j in A that match by note that B[:, i] - A[:, j] = 0
so for the simple case you described above we can just do:

```
m = []
for b in B[0]:
    m.append((np.argmin(np.abs(A[0] - b))))
```

for a sparse matrix, if there is some i and j s.t A[:, i] = A[:, j], m is not unique but we could get a possible m with a simliear approach

```
m = []
for i in range(B.shape[1]):
    m.append((np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(A - np.tile(B[:, i].reshape(-1, 1), shape[1]), axis=0))))
```